# How to force OpenSSL to use old ciphers

Tags: bash, ssl, openssl, macports

I'm trying to check the "security" certificate on an APC power distribution unit using OpenSSL from this shell script, but kept getting back an empty response.

```
#!/bin/bash
host=192.168.242.27
port=443
cert=$(openssl s_client -connect "$host":"$port" 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/BEGIN CERT/,/END CERT/p')
echo "We got a cert:"
echo $cert
```

So I did some debugging. I'm on a Mac, and have a MacPorts environment. Using the MacPorts version of OpenSSL to connect to the server, I get nothing:

```
❱ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016

❱ openssl s_client -connect 192.168.242.27:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
140735258415184:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 308 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1464972048
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

But, using the built-in version I get a response:

```
❱ /usr/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

❱ /usr/bin/openssl s_client -connect 192.168.242.27:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 /C=US/ST=Default State/L=Default Locality/O=American Power Conversion Corp/OU=Internally Generated Certificate/CN=5A1320E05051
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=US/ST=Default State/L=Default Locality/O=American Power Conversion Corp/OU=Internally Generated Certificate/CN=5A1320E05051
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Default State/L=Default Locality/O=American Power Conversion Corp/OU=Internally Generated Certificate/CN=5A1320E05051
   i:/C=US/ST=Default State/L=Default Locality/O=American Power Conversion Corp/OU=Internally Generated Certificate/CN=5A1320E05051
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Default State/L=Default Locality/O=American Power Conversion Corp/OU=Internally Generated Certificate/CN=5A1320E05051
issuer=/C=US/ST=Default State/L=Default Locality/O=American Power Conversion Corp/OU=Internally Generated Certificate/CN=5A1320E05051
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 848 bytes and written 280 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-MD5
Server public key is 768 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-MD5
    Session-ID: E07867E677700F3E7F69FFCC96B4A158
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 16CB13EF51575C010EB50D37C353A276C108B6673D5FEFEA7B196F84C7ECD858AC00A3137C5AAB9758C50ED35B92BC8B
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1464972023
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
```

(Yes, that is RC4-MD5 cipher on a 2 year old piece of hardware; and no, I don't recommend anyone purchase one of these things.)

In production, I want to be able to do this from a Linux server where I will only have access to OpenSSL 1.0.2. I've tried with all sorts of arguments to `openssl s_client` to disable and enable various combinations of SSL and TLS with no luck. So, is there a way to get a modern version of OpenSSL to talk to a device with weak crypto?

Comment: I know this could be considered off-topic, but I am doing this as part of a Bash shell script; so programming, right?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Related, you have a self signed certificate that's not well formed: ***`/C=US/ST=Default State/L=Default Locality/O=American Power Conversion Corp/OU=Internally Generated Certificate/CN=5A1320E05051`***. There's no ***`Subject Alternate Name`*** with `192.168.242.27` as a hostname (use something like `pbpaste | openssl x509 -text -noout`). Nearly every user agent will reject it. OpenSSL does not reject it because OpenSSL 1.0.2 and earlier did *not* perform hostname matching. OpenSSL 1.1.0 will perform hostname matching, so brace for all the devops questions that will follow.

Comment: @jww yes, it's the default one that came with the device; I'm trying to pull all the certs so I know which ones need to be replaced with ones from our CA. And indeed, management of these things is limited to SSH since browsers stopped accepting 768-bit keys. Now they all need firmware updates as well, so they can handle a 1024-bit key and one extra cipher. It's very poor security for a device that's being sold in 2016.

Comment: To answer your immediate question, you can use old protocols and ciphers with something like `openssl s_client -connect 192.168.242.27:443 -ssl3 -cipher 'AES-SHA'`. If you are using TLS 1.0 and above with SNI, then `openssl s_client -connect 192.168.242.27:443 -tls1 -servername -cipher 'HIGH:!aNULL:!RC4:!MD5'`. Also see [`s_client` man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html).

Comment: *"It's very poor security for a device that's being sold in 2016...."* - Lol... So are all the Verizon/Actiontec routers with the same public/private keypair. Your device probably suffers the same. There's a registry of them at devttys0's GitHub [littleblackbox](http://github.com/devttys0/littleblackbox/tree/master/docs).

Comment: "AES-SHA"? No, this thing does 56-bit DES, or 128-bit RC4-MD5 and RC4-SHA. That's all. So no way this will work without a recompile unfortunately.

Comment: @milken - try listing your ciphers with `$ openssl ciphers -v 'HIGH:!aNULL:!RC4:!MD5' | cut -f 1 -d " "`. You should see `AES128-SHA`, `AES128-SHA256`, `AES256-SHA` and `AES256-SHA256`. There's nothing weak about SHA1 used in a MAC. The TLS Payload/PDU has a TTL in minutes from the underlying transport. There are no forgery attacks that can be carried out in minutes that I am aware. SHA1 used in a certificate is a different story because they survive for years, not minutes.

Comment: No I'm saying the web interface on the PDU doesn't do AES. A cipher list of `HIGH:!aNULL:!RC4:!MD5` knocks out everything this thing can do.

Comment: RC4 (nonexport) has nominal strength 128 bits (in spite of rfc7465) and OpenSSL has always put it in MEDIUM (not LOW). My source build of untweaked upstream 1.0.2h on CentOS (I don't have Mac) does include nonexport RC4 suites and they work. Did/can you try `openssl ciphers -v RC4` or `openssl ciphers -v |grep RC4`? It might be protocol not (just) cipher; try `s_client` with `-tls1`?

Comment: It looks like you will probably have to use [SSH to access the device](http://www.apcmedia.com/salestools/JSAI-7WFQKR/JSAI-7WFQKR_R4_EN.pdf?sdirect=true) (if that's the same device you are using). Otherwise, you might make a quick pass with [sslscan](http://www.google.com/search?q=sslscan+gihub) to see the full list of cipher suites that are supported. As far as I know, the GitHub sslscan's are a fork of the [original SourceForge sslscan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sslscan/) which appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's programming, because you likely have to build your own from source.

See this [from the OpenSSL 1.0.2g changelog](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x2):

> - Disable weak ciphers in SSLv3 and up in default builds of OpenSSL.
>     Builds that are not configured with "enable-weak-ssl-ciphers" will not
>     provide any "EXPORT" or "LOW" strength ciphers.
>     [Viktor Dukhovni]
> - Disable SSLv2 default build, default negotiation and weak ciphers. 
>     SSLv2
>     is by default disabled at build-time.  Builds that are not configured with
>     "enable-ssl2" will not support SSLv2.

Comment: That's it, thanks. There are no plans to [allow those flags into MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/50865) either, for the record.

Comment: It's _not_ programming. The quoted changelog states that you can enable this by re-building the software: "Builds that are not configured [to do so] will not provide any [...] "LOW" strength ciphers."

Comment: @jpaugh There's a [tag for 'build'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build).  And [Wikipedia disagrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming): "Computer programming is the process of designing and **building** an executable computer program to accomplish a specific computing result or to perform a particular task."

Comment: You're right that building is part of programming. But, it is not exclusive to programming, and often requires a fair bit less technical knowledge. My point was only that "power users" shouldn't be scared off from building apps. (I was looking at several SE sites for a solution, and misunderstood your reason for adding that statement. I'm surprised to notice, now, that this question is actually on [SO], and not [SU]. But... whatever.)

Comment: FWIW, a well-polished code release with good documentation and an automated build process can make building a fairly straightforward endeavor. Having said that, a less-polished build process requires varying degrees of other programming skills.